# If $n\mid ab - 1$ then $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In my course notes there is a proof to the identity:

> $[a]_n$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z} \iff gcd(a,n) = 1$. With $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$ and $ a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

And then in the proof there is this step which I do not understand and cannot explain: $n\mid ab - 1 \Rightarrow \gcd(a,n) =\gcd(b,n) = 1$. Is there someone that can guide me to the answer?

Comment: Okay seems like Mathjax didn't work for me..

Comment: It seems you have not looked into a manual - see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for example.

Comment: @Moeee I fixed it for you. Use dollar signs around the expressions.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $n\mid ab-1$, then there is some integer $c$ such that $cn=ab-1$, or $ab-cn=1$.  Since 1 is a linear combination of $a$ and $n$, $(a,n)=1$ and similarly for $(b,n)=1$.

Comment: (+1) I was just about to post something similar.

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ and $a$ have any common factors, then $n$ and $ab$ have the same factors, and possibly more, in common. Say $\gcd(n, ab) = d>1$. In that case $ab-1$ cannot possibly be a multiple of $n$, as $ab-n = 1$ would imply that $d\mid 1$.

Same thing for $n$ and $b$.

Comment: $\large \begin{align}{\rm i.e.}\ \  \ (n,a)\mid (n,&\ \color{#c00}{ab})\! =\! (n,\color{#c00}1)\! =\! 1\\[.3em] {\rm by}\, \ \bmod n\!:&\,\ \color{#c00}{ab\,\equiv\, 1}\\
{\rm Generally}\ \   (n,a)&\mid nk,ab\,\Rightarrow\,  \bbox[6px,border:1px solid #c00]{(n,a)\mid (nk,ab)}
\end{align}\quad$